# React Form data gets lost on slow network after re-render of form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reactjs

I have a form on react Component.
When i load the react application on Slow 3G network on chrome , as the bundle size is 1MB it takes 2-3 minutes to load the bundle but the form is loaded before the bundle loads.

So if we enter any details on form , they get lost once the bundle is loaded and the form is re-rendered.

Is there a way to fill the form with the previously entered details.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches for this problem:

1. Use **lazy loading**, split your code into multiple bundles. This feature is ready to use in `create-react-app`. I attached a code example [here](https://github.com/changx03/react-lazy-loading-example).
2. In `onblur` event, try to save the value in **local storage** (eg: `localStorage.setItem('input', value)`). However, this is not guarantee to work due to the incomplete bundle file. To overcome this, it's better to split bundle first. And try save it inside your component rather than inside Redux action.
   Assuming you're using Redux, and the input values are saved in component's state with 2-way binding. (*Input will not update, if this it can't `setState`*)
3. Adding a loading icon, only allows user input data until bundle download completely. (This might not the best solution, but definitely the easiest.)

**Note:**

- This problem actually might not as big as you think, due to mobile browser also save caches. So if you've opened the page already, it might not download the bundle at all.
- *Development* build is also way bigger than *Production* build due to the extra `source-map` and without `uglify`, make sure you test your app with production build.

Comment: I was testing with production build. Is it possible to use refs and get the value from fields and set them back once component is loaded.

Comment: @Nayeem your browser typically saves these value after login. If you can see the login form, it means the browser definitely has the code for rendering the form. I would give save local storage a try, and then remove them on submit